# Apply increment operator to a function

Tags: c++

Is there a case where this would be valid C++ code?

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    ++f(k);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if `f` returns a reference.

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    ++f(k);
}

int & f(int & k) {
    return k;
}
```

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments, there is another possibility: you can call `++f(k)`, if `f` returns a class type and it has the `++operator(void)` overloaded as a member function.

Comment: Also, if `f` returns an object of class type, with an overloaded `operator++`. The overload is a member function, and you *can* call a member function on an _rvalue_.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: thanks for pointing this out, I did try this with int, and it did not work, but did not try with a class type. My fault.

Comment: Indeed, it won't work for non-class types; the built-in operator can only be applied to an _lvalue_, while member functions can also be called on an _rvalue_.

Comment: That's what I like about stackoverflow, even if you just answer questions you still learn a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one, it would work if you preceded that code with:

```
#define f
```

but that's not applying the increment operator to a *function,* as you seem to desire in your title. If you try to apply it to a function as below:

```
int f (int x) { return x + 1; }
```

you will get the error:

```
error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

because the returned value is not an `lvalue` (obviously). You *can* return a reference to a variable which can then be incremented thus:

```
#include <iostream>
int xyzzy = 42;
int & f(int x) { return xyzzy; }
int main() {
    int k = 0;
    ++f(k);
    std::cout << xyzzy << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This works because the returned reference references the `xyzzy` variable; it outputs:

```
43
```

Comment: Any case where this would be useful?

Comment: @Petros, assuming you mean the `#define` bit, probably not. The reference bit I could see being potentially useful, but I'm sure there's better ways to do that as well.

Answer (score 3):

The function `f` will be run before the ++ pre-operator, This is due to [precedence of operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You are not incrementing the function but the value it returns. So this code would only be valid if the value returned by `f(k)` can be incremented.

In short, yes, this code is valid in a lot of cases (when the object f returns is not const and can be incremented).

Answer (score 1):

`f()` could return a reference that you want to increase after returning from the function. for example:

```
int someGlobal;
int& f(int k) {
 return someGlobal;
}
```

Though it is wrong in many ways [designically speaking]

Answer (score 1):

In the obvious case that `f` has the signature `int f(int)` or some equivalent, no: you cannot use `++` on a temporary. It would not even compile.

If it's made to compile by some other trick (such as `f` returning a reference) then there's still the matter that code like this is an example of what to avoid.

So it all depends on what you mean by *valid*: it can be valid as the compiler is concerned, but IMO it's not valid in the sense that I could read this code and not have some choice things to say about the author.

Comment: Yes, by valid I mean compilable.

Answer (score 1):

Sure: Suppose you want one more than a square number:

```
int & square(int & n)
{
    n = n * n;
    return n;
}
```

Now you can say,

```
int k;
++f(k);
```

and it has the same effect as `int k = 0 * 0 + 1;`. The example is not so exciting for `0`, but makes sense in general. It's questionable whether it is good style to have a function both mutate the argument and return a reference to it, but the pre-increment has the same semantics, and you can write `++square(++square(k))` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

When f returns an int&, for example.

Comment: @delnan: An `int&` *is* an lvalue.

Comment: @celtschk I'm pretty certain the answer used to say `int`, and it seems at least one person agreed (my comment has +1 and the answer used to have a downvote). Anyway, removed it now.

Comment: @delnan: I thought of that possibility, but SO didn't display an edit of the answer (and still doesn't). Can an edit disappear?

Comment: @celtschk Edits within the first few minutes are never shown, or at least have never been shown to me.

Comment: @delnan Yes, the answer was initially about int, not int&. I saw it too :). But anyways, this answer is now correct.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :)